# Get Django variable in Javascript : undefined value

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a little issue and I don't overcome to solve it. I have a `list of Django objects` generated in my `views.py` file and I would like to display these variables in my `Javascript` part.

I get the list in my Javascript code, but each variable are `'undefined'`.

In my views.py file, I have :

```
context['results2'] = SubMethod.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).all()
```

with this model :

```
class SubMethod(EdqmTable):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('name'), max_length=80, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, in my HTML/JS part :

```
function get_sub_method_options(keep_cur) {
  var sel_option = $('select#id_method-group').find("option:selected");
  var sel_val = sel_option.val();
  if (!sel_val) {
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").empty();
    var all_sub_methods = "{{ results2 }}";
    console.log(all_sub_methods.name);
      for (var i = 0; i < all_sub_methods.length; i++) {
        $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + all_sub_methods[i].id + '">' + all_sub_methods[i].name + '</option>'); //here add list of all submethods
      }
    return;
  }

  data = {
    'test_method': $('select#id_method-test_method').find("option:selected").val(),
    'group': sel_val
  };
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: '{% url 'ajax_method_submethod' %}',
    data: data

  }).done(function (result) {
    reset_select('id_method-sub_method');
    for (var i = 0; i < result['results'].length; i++) {
      if (keep_cur > 0 & keep_cur == result['results'][i].id)
        $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + result['results'][i].id + '" selected>' + result['results'][i].text + '</option>');
      else
        $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + result['results'][i].id + '">' + result['results'][i].text + '</option>');
    }
    ;
  });
}
```

As you can see, I pick up my context variable `result2` in this part :

```
if (!sel_val) {
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").empty();
    var all_sub_methods = "{{ results2 }}";
    console.log(all_sub_methods.name);
      for (var i = 0; i < all_sub_methods.length; i++) {
        $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + all_sub_methods[i].id + '">' + all_sub_methods[i].name + '</option>'); //here add list of all submethods
      }
    return;
  }
```

In my terminal I get :

```
<QuerySet ['50% cell culture infective dose (CCID50)', 'Acetic acid in synthetic peptides', 'Acid value', 'Adenylate cyclase', ...]>
```

But in my Javascript part, it displays this :

[image]

Do you have any idea why ?

**EDIT :**

In my django code, `count()` displays 450

In my JS code : `length` display 684

In my database : I have 450 elements

Comment: How would you return back the `result` from view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your queryset to a list first. JS does not read querysets.

```
context['results2'] = list(SubMethod.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).all())
```

and you may want to skip wrapping `results2` in quotes on the JS side and ass safe` to prevent escaping characters:

```
var all_sub_methods = {{ results2|safe }};
```

Comment: If I add `list()` it still remains `undefined` and I get `length : 21450`. It counts each character ?

Comment: I found a solution thanks to your method and some modifications in my code. Thank you very much !